# how to tell which ini file the current uwsgi process is using?

Tags: django, uwsgi

In an operating website with Nginx, Uwsgi and Django. and it has tons of venv and django projects. Is it any way I can tell with .ini file the uwsgi loaded?

I ran "ps aux | grep uwsgi" and it shows this:

```
ubuntu    2136  0.0  0.4 108280 32872 pts/1    S+   Mar29  22:58 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu    9337  0.0  0.4 111312 34836 pts/1    S+   Jul11   0:05 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu    9893  0.0  0.4 111572 34836 pts/1    S+   Jul11   0:07 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu    9980  0.0  0.4 300744 37496 pts/6    Sl+  Jul11   0:07 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   12442  0.1  0.4 300752 37520 pts/6    Sl+  Jul11   0:07 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   12663  0.1  0.4 111548 34872 pts/1    S+   Jul11   0:08 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   15462  0.1  0.4 300752 37520 pts/6    Sl+  00:22   0:05 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   15767  0.1  0.4 111568 34852 pts/1    S+   00:25   0:09 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   17740  0.1  0.4 300752 37524 pts/6    Sl+  00:43   0:05 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   18874  0.0  0.4 107356 33944 pts/5    S+   May15   2:02 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   18876  0.0  0.4 110272 33856 pts/5    S+   May15   0:00 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   18877  0.0  0.4 110368 34068 pts/5    S+   May15   0:00 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   20763  0.1  0.4 300744 37504 pts/6    Sl+  01:12   0:04 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   22143  0.0  0.4 301004 37716 pts/6    Sl+  Jul11   0:10 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   25620  0.0  0.0  13772  1104 pts/0    S+   01:54   0:00 grep --color=auto uwsgi
ubuntu   25915  0.0  0.4 301132 38492 pts/6    Sl+  Jul11   0:11 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   27713  0.0  0.4 300756 37508 pts/6    Sl+  Jul11   0:10 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   28648  0.0  0.3  92948 29528 pts/4    S+   May15   2:02 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   28650  0.0  0.4 300576 36920 pts/4    Sl+  May15   0:01 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   28651  0.0  0.4 300484 36812 pts/4    Sl+  May15   0:00 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   30146  0.0  0.3  93864 31336 pts/6    S+   May15  12:38 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   30187  0.0  0.4 113104 36372 pts/1    S+   Jul11   0:07 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   30910  0.0  0.4 113088 36492 pts/1    S+   Jul11   0:07 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   32262  0.0  0.4 112852 36404 pts/1    S+   Jul11   0:06 uwsgi repository.ini
ubuntu   32618  0.0  0.4 113100 36756 pts/1    S+   Jul11   0:08 uwsgi repository.ini
```

but I could not tell which repository.ini is running.

Answer (score 2):

If you have run your application following [the docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) you can do
`ps aux | grep uwsgi` and should see a list of `uwsgi` instances (if you have multiple) and their corresponding `ini` file. you can then look up the `.ini` file to check which is running which

Comment: Thank you. but I couldn't tell which ini was it.

Comment: Is it running in docker?
you can also setup [uwsgi stats](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/StatsServer.html) or you could instantiate your uwsgi instances using full path of your ini file so you could know which is corresponding to which.

You can also assign pidfile to your process for management 

Also share your uwsgi file